# index out of bounds in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a smp dataframe with  :

```
loser_ioc winner_ioc 
AUT       IND
```

So il would like to count the occurance of each country and use a list for that :

```
country <- list()
for (i in 1:Size){
  if (is.null(country[[smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]])) {
    country[[ smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]] = 1
  } else {
    country[[ smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]] =  country[[ smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]] + 1
  }
  if (is.null(l[[ smp[i, "loser_ioc"]]])) {
    country[[ smp[i, "loser_ioc"]]] = 1
  } else {
    country[[ smp[i, "loser_ioc"]]] =  country[[ smp[i, "loser_ioc"]]] + 1
  }
}
countryD <- data.frame(country) 
write.csv(countryD, file = "country.csv")
```

but i have an index out of bounds error ...

```
Error in country[[smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]] : subscript out of bounds
```

thanks and regards

Comment: I think you can simply apply `table()`  to each column to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert the smp in string to use it as an index  :

```
country <- list()
for (i in 1:Size) {
  if (is.null(country[[toString(smp[i, "winner_ioc"])]])) {
    country[[ smp[i, "winner_ioc"]]] = 1
  } else {
    country[[ toString(smp[i, "winner_ioc"])]] =  country[[ toString(smp[i, "winner_ioc"])]] + 1
  }
  if (is.null(country[[ toString(smp[i, "loser_ioc"])]])) {
    country[[ toString(smp[i, "loser_ioc"])]] = 1
  } else {
    country[[ toString(smp[i, "loser_ioc"])]] =  country[[ toString(smp[i, "loser_ioc"])]] + 1
  }
}
countryD <- data.frame(country) 
write.csv(countryD, file = "country.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a matrix of who beats who using `table(smp)`

```
     winner
loser AUD CAD MEX NZD USA
  AUD   0   0   0   1   1
  CAD   0   1   0   0   2
  MEX   3   0   0   1   0
  NZD   2   1   0   0   0
  USA   0   0   1   0   1
```

Or can do this with `spreading` the columns and then `grouping` and `counting` in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(loser = sample(c("AUT", "USA", "NZ", "CAD", "MEX"), 14, replace = TRUE), 
                winner = sample(c("AUT", "USA", "NZ", "CAD", "MEX"), 14, replace = TRUE))

new_x <- x %>% gather(result, who, c(winner, loser)) %>% group_by_all() %>% count()


> x %>% gather(result, who, c(winner, loser)) %>% group_by_all() %>% count()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   result, who [10]
   result   who     n
    <chr> <chr> <int>
 1  loser   AUD     2
 2  loser   CAD     3
 3  loser   MEX     4
 4  loser   NZD     3
 5  loser   USA     2
 6 winner   AUD     5
 7 winner   CAD     2
 8 winner   MEX     1
 9 winner   NZD     2
10 winner   USA     4
```